# How do I run a python file in pylab, which executes another python file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, execfile

I want to create a startup configuration that runs a file that I request. So far, my  configuration file is as follows:

```
path1=input('What folder would you like to open?')

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Spring 2013\\CSCI_278\\'+path1)

doc=input('What file would  you like to open and run?')

open(doc)

execfile(doc)
```

but the `execfile` doesn't work for some reason, and I end having to use `%run` in pylab anyway.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Does using [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of `input` solve your problem?

Not sure you need the `open(doc)` line.

The code below works on my machine:

```
doc = raw_input('What file would  you like to open and run?')

execfile(doc)
```

Note that you can also use the line below instead, if you do not want to type the ".py" each time

```
doc = "%s.py" % raw_input('What file would  you like to open and run?')
```